Next JS not rendering images on production for no apparent reason
I am tearing my hair with this one.
I made a site with Next.js 14 and on dev all works great, doing build and then start also works great on my local machine but when I put it on the server...
Some images refuse to display, with a 404.
I am using almost identical JSX for both, but one displays and another does not
The one that displays:
<Image
  src='/images/alvaro.jpg'
  alt='Portrait'
  width={100}
  height={100}
  quality={95}
  priority={true}
  className='h-24 w-24 rounded-full object-cover border-[0.15rem] border-[#f1f1f1] shadow-lg'
/>

And the one that does not:
<Image
  src='/images/english.jpg'
  width={50}
  height={50}
  alt='English'
  quality={95}
  priority={true}
  onClick={() => handleLanguage('en')}
  className={clsx(
    'cursor-pointer rounded-full shadow-md object-cover border-[0.12rem] border-[#f1f1f1] dark:border-0 hover:scale-110 transition',
    {
      'opacity-75': activeLang === 'es'
    }
  )}
/>

The files are both on the same folder /public/images and are all lowercase.
I have no idea what is going on. Why would it work on my machine and then not on the server one yes one not?
The 404 says cannot find /_next/image?url=/images/english.jpg&w=64&q=95
But has not problem getting /_next/image?url=%2Fimages%2Falvaro.jpg&w=256&q=95


Note one of them is /_next/image?url=%2Fimages%2Falvaro.jpg&w=256&q=95 and the other _next/image?url=/images/english.jpg&w=64&q=95 (no back slash at the beggining)

No that was my bad tryping

Url pattern is different in each src, check backslash around images (/images/ and %2Fimages%2)

Why would that be? the original Jsx is the same for both

have you tried importing the file and rendered it in the src instead of inserting a relative path, like this:
import MyImg from "path/alvaro.jpg"

<Image src={MyImg} alt={alt} width={width} height={height} />

React has a dynamic way of displaying images

Thanks. No I have not, will give this I try. In the end I did a deployment with Vercel and all worked out but will try a manual standalone again a use that method
